# Create Shortcode shows only posts with custom_field meta

Tags: custom-field, shortcode, meta-query, meta-value

I want to create a shortcode, which shows only the posts that have the definite meta_value. I use the ACF Plugin for different meta-fields.
I have the post type "publication" and e.g. want to show only the Publications, which are released in 2017 with this shortcode [Publication 2017] or Publication release-Date 2017].

```
function shortcode_display_publication_details(){

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'publication',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key'          => 'release-date',
    'meta_value' => '2017',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'order'             => 'DESC',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    echo  the_field('autor'). " (" ;
    echo  the_field('release-date'). ") ";
    echo  the_field('buch'). ". ";
    echo '<b>' . get_the_title() . '</b>'. ", ";
    echo  the_field('verleger'). ". " ;
    if (get_field('seiten')){
    echo  "S. ";
    echo the_field('seiten'). ". <p />" ;
    }
    echo '<p>';
    echo '&nbsp;';

endwhile;

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();

}
// Register the shortcodes.
add_shortcode( 'publication', 'shortcode_display_publication_details' );
```

This Shortcode shows only the Publications of 2017. But I don't want to build a extra Shortcode for every year.
How does it work, that I can create a Shortcode with custom meta_value like this 
    [Publication YEARXXXX]
?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need your shortcode to accept attributes. A shortcode with attributes would look like:

```
[publication year="2017"]
```

Then in your `add_shortcode` callback function you receive attributes in the first parameter of the function:

```
function wpse_279094_publication_shortcode( $atts ) {
    echo $atts['year'];
}
add_shortcode( 'publication', 'wpse_279094_shortcode' );
```

You want to be able to account for a user not using any attributes, so you use the `shortcode_atts()` function to populate `$atts` with defaults if they aren't set. In your use case the current year seems like a logical default. So that would look like:

```
function wpse_279094_publication_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( 
        array(
            'year' => date('Y')
        ),
        $atts
    );
}
add_shortcode( 'publication', 'wpse_279094_shortcode' );
```

So, all together that your code should look like:

```
function wpse_279094_publication_shortcode(){
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array( 'year' => date('Y') ), $atts );

    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'publication',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_key'       => 'release-date',
        'meta_value'     => $atts['year'],
        'orderby'        => 'meta_value',
        'order'          => 'DESC',
        'post_status'    => 'publish'
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    ob_start();

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        echo the_field( 'autor' ). " (" ;
        echo the_field( 'release-date' ). ") ";
        echo the_field( 'buch' ). ". ";
        echo '<b>' . get_the_title() . '</b>'. ", ";
        echo the_field( 'verleger' ). ". " ;
        if ( get_field( 'seiten' ) ) {
            echo "S. ";
            echo the_field( 'seiten' ). ". <p />" ;
        }
        echo '<p>';
        echo '&nbsp;';
    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();

    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'publication', 'wpse_279094_publication_shortcode' );
```

Now you can use `[publication year="2017"]`, `[publication year="2012"]` etc. to get publications from different years, or `[publication]` to get publications from the current year.

Also note one other change I made to your code. In your code you just `echo`ed your output. Shortcodes need to `return` their output, otherwise the contents won't appear in the right place.

One way to do this is to just build up a large string:

```
$output = get_the_title();
$output .= get_the_content();

return $output;
```

But I find that cumbersome. Instead, I used `ob_start()` which will 'capture' all the output without echoing it to the screen. Then, I `return` `ob_get_clean()` to return the captured output.

Comment: My Comment were deleted... So I try it once again:

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried out your code, but it works only for 2017. I used the shortcode:  [publication year="2016"], but I get only the publications of 2017. Maybe I have to get the meta_value otherwise? Like this: 'meta_key' => get_field('release-date'), 'meta_value' => $atts['year'], This dosn't work, but maybe it's the right approach? would be very happy, if you culd help me. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: No that's not how `meta_key` works. What type of ACF field is `release-date`?

Comment: Now it works, I forget to add the $atts here: function wpse_279094_publication_shortcode( $atts ). Thank you a lot for your help!